# Checkbox validtion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, checkbox

Hi i have checkboxes and submit button.And for validation i need atleast 1 checkbox should be checked while clicking on submit button.I tried few ways in jquery but now working.Thank you.
Here is my code:

dashboard.php

```
<table id="fahrzeuge" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" checked />
            <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl Fahrzeuge ohne Bilder</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" value="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" checked />
            <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" id="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" value="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" checked />
            <label for="Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern">Fahrzeuge mit Fehlern</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Herausforderungen" id="Herausforderungen" value="Herausforderungen" checked />
            <label for="Herausforderungen">Herausforderungen</label><br><br>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

dashboard.js

```
function getFahrzeuge() { 
    var opts = [];
    $("#fahrzeuge input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
        }
    }); 
    return opts;
}

$('#fahrzeuge .butt-rahmen').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveId')
    {
        var opts = getFahrzeuge();
        saveFahrzeugeWidget(opts);                                
    }
});
```

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? `live` is long deprecated and removed since 1.9

Comment: Define "not working". Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: i m using old query version and i am not getting any error just i want to validate it...

Comment: i have changed it now to onclick function...

Comment: I can't see any `.butt-rahmen` in your HTML. Are they added later? If so, use the event delegation syntax of `on`.

Comment: its predefined format for button id for my project..if you know please tell me ?

Comment: Try with `$('#fahrzeuge').on('click', '.butt-rahmen', function(){...`

Comment: Please see below link, You can use given js code "http://jsfiddle.net/kxy8u/12/"

Comment: @asprin i tried and its not the solution u gave ...i am asking for validation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the check using `:checked` selector:

```
if($("#fahrzeuge input:checked").length){
   //atleast one checked
}
```

Comment: Asker's approach shouldn't cause any issue, though, can it?

Comment: @JanDvorak: there is no code that checks the validation he is asking for.